# HeadlessUI Tabs active tabs gets back to 0 after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, tailwind-css, headless-ui

I badly need help about headlessUI tabs. I was trying to fix it my own and research but there's not enough resources about my problem. I still don't understand how this is not working, I also read the docs.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Tab } from "@headlessui/react";

function classNames(...classes) {
  return classes.filter(Boolean).join(" ");
}

export default function Tabs({ tabs }) {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState();

  return (
    <Tab.Group
      defaultIndex={index}
      onChange={(index) => {
        console.log("Changed selected tab to:", index);
        setIndex(index);
      }}
    >
      <Tab.List className="text-xl space-x-9">
        {tabs.map(({ tab }, index) => (
          <Tab
            key={index}
            className={({ selected }) =>
              classNames(
                selected ? "text-gray-900" : "text-gray-400 font-avenir-roman"
              )
            }
          >
            {tab}
          </Tab>
        ))}
      </Tab.List>
      <Tab.Panels>
        {tabs.map(({ content }, index) => (
          <Tab.Panel key={index}>{content}</Tab.Panel>
        ))}
      </Tab.Panels>
    </Tab.Group>
  );
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? defaultIndex={index} will set it back to the first tab, that's expected. You have to manage the state yourself based on url query or params or localStorage or something ..

Comment: I already fix it using the localStorage, it's working now. Thank you 

Comment: Provide an answer yourself then so this is helpful to others as well.

Comment: I used router.push() with shallow routing in nextjs to change the url without refreshing the page

Comment: I think what @trainoasis means is that you should post an answer under this question about your own solution so that other people who come through can easily find how you fixed it.

Comment: yea, id like an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is what I did to persist the currentTab**

```
const [currentTab, setCurrentTab] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("currentTab", JSON.stringify(currentTab));
  }, [currentTab]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const currentTab = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentTab"));
    if (currentTab) {
      setCurrentTab(currentTab);
    }
  }, []);

 <Tab.Group
            defaultIndex={tab}
            onChange={(currentTab) => {
              setCurrentTab(currentTab);
              router.replace(
                {
                  pathname: `/path/userPath/edit/${id}`,
                  query: { tab: currentTab },
                },
                undefined,
                {
                  shallow: true,
                }
              );
            }}
          >
```

**UPDATE:** You can also use the `query.tab` to persist the tab.

Answer (score 0):

Found an **easy way** of doing this using URL query parameter. First of all add query parameter using onClick on the each Tab component.

`{BASEURL}?tab={tab_name}`

Then create a function like as follows;

```
const router = useRouter();

const getActiveTab = () => {
    const tabValues = ["tab1","tab2"]; //This should contains the all the tab_names you given earlier when calling onClick.

    return tabValues.indexOf(router.query.tab);
  };
```

After that set the defaultIndex attribute of the Tab.Group Component to be equal to the return value of the function as follows;

```
<Tab.Group defaultIndex={getActiveTab()}>
  <Tab.List>
  </Tab.List>
<Tab.Group/>
```